# How to get input for days of the week to always be sorted M-Su

Tags: java, android, string

I'm using some java code and android to get some input from the user based on checkboxes clicked. Each of these checkboxes correspond to days of the week, so M, T, W, Th, F, S and Su are all the possible string values.

If the user clicks M-Su in order, the string will come out as "M, T, W, Th..." etc. in order. But if he clicks them in any different order, well as you can guess it just puts it based on what is clicked first. I already deal with the logic of removing the string values if they uncheck the box but was a little confused as to how I should go about setting up a system where M is always first, then T, and W and Su is always last.

The user can click only "Su, M, F" as their options but I want it to appear as "M, F, Su" after it orders it.

I was thinking maybe using a hashmap to create a priority system for the strings to do some comparison, but haven't done this before and was wondering how should I go about doing this the most efficient way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that maps the days to numbers which can then be sorted accordingly. Another way to do this might be through the use of an enum containing a String value which is the abbreviation of the day and an int value which is the numeric value e.g:

```
public enum Days{

    Sunday("Su", 1),
    Monday("M", 2);

    String day;
    int val;

    Days(String day, int val) {
        this.day = day;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

From here, you could then perhaps implement static functions to get an enum value from a String or an int. This way, from a given input from the user, you can store the associated int and when you want to get the corresponding String value, you can just use your implemented method to get the associated String.

Comment: Can you give an example of this in work, with the sorting you mentioned? Haven't used enums before. Thanks!